# R - Create valid json with input from R objects

Tags: r, json, string, jsonlite

I am looking to create a valid JSON string, with input from an R list.
Each  key and value needs to be quotation escaped (see expected valid JSON). I use jsonlite package for transform to JSON.

The result string is used for an API that requires the quotation escapes.

R-list:

```
myProducts <- list(
                  productOne = "x",
                  productTwo = "y"
)
```

Convert list to json format:

```
myJSON <- toJSON(myProducts)
```

Output:

```
{"productOne":["x"],"productTwo":["y"]}
```

Expected valid json / Neeed string:

`"{\"productOne\": \"x\", \"productTwo\": \"y\"}"`

Comment: `gsub('"','\\\\"', myJSON)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get the expected string:

```
> as.character(toJSON(myProducts, auto_unbox = TRUE))
[1] "{\"productOne\":\"x\",\"productTwo\":\"y\"}"
```